# If $(G, \cdot)$ is a monoid, then $(\mathcal{P}(G), \cup, \cdot)$is a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, monoid

> Let $(G, \cdot)$ be a monoid. On $\mathcal{P}(G)=\{ X \mid X \subseteq G \}$ we define an operation deduced from $\cdot$, namely, if $A, B \in \mathcal{P}(G), AB=\{ab \mid a \in A \land b \in B\} \;$(here $\land$ is the logical and).

Take $A, B, C \in \mathcal{P}(G)$
$$A(B \cup C)=A \cdot \{t \mid t \in B \lor t \in C \}=\{ at \mid a \in A \land (t \in B \lor t \in C) \} = \{ at \mid (a \in A \land t \in B) \lor (a \in A \land t \in C) \}=AB \cup AC$$
Analogously, for $(B \cup C)\cdot A$.

Is my proof rigorous and can we say $A(B \cap C)=AB \cap C$ or $A(B \cap C)=B \cap AC$? And are there any more studied operations that are known to be distributive? For example the symmetric difference and intersection could form a ring, but are there any other known combinations?

Comment: I don't understand what your last bit has to do with the first.

Comment: Just for context, to explain why i cared about the first bit. But you are right it is quite not necessary

Comment: Consider the natural numbers under addition (my natural numbers include $0$, so it's a monoid). Take $A=\{1\}$, $B$ the even nonnegative numbers, and $C$ the odd positive numbers. Then $A(B\cap C) = A\varnothing = \varnothing$, but $AB\cap C= C$, and $B\cap AC$ is all positive even numbers. Neither is equal to $A(B\cap C)$. For a finite example take the additive group of integers modulo an even number.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thank you for the response. I was also wondering whether or not $A(B \cup C)=AB \cup AC$. And if so, is my proof rigurous?